# Gmagick: Gravity constants are defined but there is no setgravity() method?

Tags: gmagick

I'm programming in PHP and trying to utilize the Gmagick extension. According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php), there is no `setgravity()` method [as there is in Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setgravity.php), yet Gmagick defines the [gravity constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.constants.php). So how does one go about setting gravity in Gmagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=gmagick&version=1.0.10b1), the gravity functions *were* added and they do appear to work, so the documentation is just out of date. The functions are just like Imagick.